# How to click a radio Button in GEB automation

Tags: grails, geb

I tried using

```
$(".formName .className").click()
```

and

```
$(".formName .className").value("MALE")
```

But these are not working

Comment: You are seriously expecting answers, presenting two tiny code snippets but no test code and no HTML, aren't you? Please read about how to ask questions here and present an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least a little more than this. The answers here are educated guesses by very dedicated users willing to help you despite this low quality question. I do admire them for trying, but I am still suggesting you to improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try selecting it by the name attribute

```
$('input', name: 'gender').value('MALE')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into using Geb Modules. They make interacting with many inputs a breeze and very readable. For example: using [Radio Buttons](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#radio-buttons-module)

Given the html…

```
<html>
    <body>
        <label for="site-current">Search this site</label>
        <input type="radio" id="site-current" name="site" value="current">

        <label for="site-google">Search Google
            <input type="radio" id="site-google" name="site" value="google">
        </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

It can be used this way…

```
def radios = $(name: "site").module(RadioButtons)
radios.checked = "current"

assert radios.checked == "current"
assert radios.checkedLabel == "Search this site"

radios.checked = "Search Google"

assert radios.checked == "google"
assert radios.checkedLabel == "Search Google"
```

Comment: I tried the above approach the following error was coming

Comment: PC:~/agile/geb-example-gradle$ ./gradlew chromeTest --stacktrace

> Task :compileTestGroovy
startup failed:
/home/agile/geb-example-gradle/src/test/groovy/GebishOrgSpec.groovy: 68: Expected a condition, but found an assignment. Did you intend to write '==' ? @ line 68, column 5.
       radios.checked = "MALE"
       ^

1 error

Comment: $(".signupForm input[name=pin]").value("560076")
    def radios = $(name: "trainer.gender").module(RadioButtons)
    radios.checked = "MALE"
    $(".signupForm input[type=SUBMIT]").click()

Comment: actually the assignment operator is giving error and the same problem is arising when i am trying to select a value from drop-down

Comment: @manab_shaw don't get discouraged, this means the modules are working. You'll have to either post a new question or debug this one yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing complicated about clicking a radio button using Geb.

Define the button using its selector:

```
static content = {
  myRadioButton{ $('#RadioButton') }
}
```

Then simply call:

```
myRadioButton.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose..You have a radio button like this

```
 <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="1"/>
  <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="1"/>

    def radioBtnClick(def radioValue){
         $("input[name='radioBtn']").value radioValue
    }
```

This Will Surely solve your Problem 
"Happy Coding"